# Dracut will not create images containing modules not in use by the current system

Tags: linux, initramfs, dracut

Ok so dracut is not performing as I believe it should and I cannot find a workaround. I have created several images before but now I am trying to create a live boot initramfs to go along with a custom live iso. every time I try the cmdlind argument below it fails and I have also tried putting the extra modules into dracut.conf but each time it gives me warnings,(which I saw on another post that they are just warnings you can ignore) but after the messages it returns to the terminal prompt and I have no option to ignore or continue with the dracut build etc.

```
#dracut.conf short and sweet
add_dracutmodules+="nfs dmsquash-live livenet "
omit_dracutmodules+="biosdevname"

#dracut terminal argument
dracut -v testinitramfs.img 

#output
dracut: Executing: /usr/bin/dracut -v testinitramfs.img
dracut: dracut module 'busybox' will not be installed, because command 'busybox' could not be found!
dracut: dracut module 'btrfs' will not be installed, because command 'btrfs' could not be found!
dracut: dracut module 'dmraid' will not be installed, because command 'dmraid' could not be found!
dracut: dracut module 'dmsquash-live-ntfs' will not be installed, because command 'ntfs-3g' could not be found!
dracut: dracut module 'livenet' depends on 'dmsquash-live', which can't be installed
dracut: dracut module 'stratis' will not be installed, because command 'stratisd-init' could not be found!
dracut: dracut module 'cifs' will not be installed, because command 'mount.cifs' could not be found!
dracut: dracut module 'dmsquash-live' cannot be found or installed.
```

and I have the packages installed I have the dracut.x86 -tools -network -caps -live -squash all installed and my available modules list shows busybox and dmsquash-live yet it still fails and says it cannot find them. Is there another dependency I am missing or more to the dracut build command that I need in this case to make those modules viewable by dracut?

```
dracut --list-modules
/etc/dracut.conf: line 8: biosdevname : command not found
bash                            crypt                         terminfo   
systemd                         dm                            udev-rules
warpclock                       dmraid                        virtfs
fips                            **dmsquash-live**                 **biosdevname**
systemd-initrd                  **dmsquash-live-ntfs**            dracut-systemd
caps                            kernel-modules                ecryptfs
systemd-networkd                kernel-modules-extra          ...
modsign                         **livenet**                       ...
rescue                          mdraid                        squash
watchdog                        multipath
**busybox**                         qemu
nss-softokn                     qemu-net
rdma                            stratis
rngd                            crypt-gpg
i18n                            crypt-loop
convertfs                       cifs
network-legacy                  debug
network-manager                 fcoe
network                         fcoe-uefi
ifcfg                           fstab-sys
url-lib                         iscsi
drm                             lunmask
plymouth                        nbd
prefixdevname                   **nfs**
prefixdevname-tools             resume
lvmmerge                        rootfs-block
btrfs                           ssh-client
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a `--no-hostonly` parameter, from man page:

```
  -H, --hostonly        Host-Only mode: Install only what is needed for
                        booting the local host instead of a generic host.
  -N, --no-hostonly     Disables Host-Only mode
```

Another common issue is to miss a package the module depends on, for example `device-mapper-multipath` is required before adding the `multipath` module.

Comment: Can confirm that this allows me to add the "livenet" module to a dracut image on Fedora 38.